# React: Reload logic on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I currently have four routes in place using the same controller:

```js
    <Route
        component={App}
        path='/'
    >
        <Route
            component={Search}
            path='/accommodation'
        />
        <Route
            component={Search}
            path='/accommodation/:state'
        />
        <Route
            component={Search}
            path='/accommodation/:state/:region'
        />
        <Route
            component={Search}
            path='/accommodation/:state/:region/:area'
        />
    </Route>
```

The component connects the `mapStateToProps` to a function that loads data from an api.

```js
// ACTIONS
// ==============================================

function mapStateToProps ({destination, properties}) {
    return {destination, properties};
}





// CONNECT & EXPORT
// ==============================================

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
    connectDataFetchers(Search, [loadSearch])
);
```

and renders a list of results.

When the route is changed to any of the others using the same controller, the data is not reloaded with a relevant call to the api to fetch the new set of results.

Is this possible to do either with react-router of any of the componentWill functions?

## SOLUTION

Thanks to @john-ruddell the following solution works:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
  if (this.props.params != nextProps.params) {
    loadSearch(nextProps.params);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add logic to request the data and your store needs to capture that and pass it down to the component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    //boolean to check if the props.params have changed
        //fetch data request
}
```

Your store needs to update with the new data that is returned. this data should be passed down to this same component as props to be rendered.

You can also update your routes to simplify it a ton

```
<Route component={App} path='/'>
    <Route path='/accommodation(/:state)(/:region)(/:area)' component={Search} />
</Route>
```

Note, the parenthesis `()` specify an optional parameter. so instead of four routes for the same component you can have only one that works in all four states :)

Comment: Love the simplified route. This may need another question but will ask here anyway but once it hits the function to load the data again the dispatch method is not completed `export function loadSearch (params) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch(
            loadDestination(params)
        ).then(() => {
            return dispatch(
                loadProperties(params)
            );
        });
    };
}`

Comment: You have to dispatch with a constant. Look at a basic redux store setup and it'll make sense :)

Comment: It was a mixture - posted the full code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996668/react-dispatch-not-firing-on-route-change/36997219#36997219

Answer (score 0):

You can modify connectDataFetchers to handle this issue. Here is the example https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall/blob/master/shared/lib/connectDataFetchers.jsx#L26

So, it tracks URL changes and runs connected action creators after change.