# React: Dispatch not firing on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have several routes that use the same controller:

```
<Route component={Search} path='/accommodation(/:state)(/:region)(/:area)' />
```

and when the route is changed I call the api function from within the component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (this.props.params != nextProps.params) {
        loadSearch(nextProps.params);
    }
}
```

which is an action as follows:

```
export function loadSearch (params) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch(
            loadDestination(params)
        ).then(() => {
            return dispatch(
                loadProperties(params)
            );
        });
    };
}
```

which loads:

```
export const DESTINATION_REQUEST = 'DESTINATION_REQUEST';
export const DESTINATION_SUCCESS = 'DESTINATION_SUCCESS';
export const DESTINATION_FAILURE = 'DESTINATION_FAILURE';

export function loadDestination (params) {
    const state = params.state ? `/${params.state}` : '';
    const region = params.region ? `/${params.region}` : '';
    const area = params.area ? `/${params.area}` : '';

    return (dispatch) => {
        return api('location', {url: `/accommodation${state}${region}${area}`}).then((response) => {
            const destination = formatDestinationData(response);

            dispatch({
                type: DESTINATION_SUCCESS,
                destination
            });
        });
    };
 }

export const PROPERTIES_REQUEST = 'PROPERTIES_REQUEST';
export const PROPERTIES_SUCCESS = 'PROPERTIES_SUCCESS';
export const PROPERTIES_FAILURE = 'PROPERTIES_FAILURE';

export function loadProperties (params, query, rows = 24) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        const locationId = getState().destination.id || 99996;

        return api('search', {locationId, rows}).then((response) => {
            const properties = response.results.map(formatPropertiesData);

            dispatch({
                type: PROPERTIES_SUCCESS,
                properties
            });
        });
    };
 }
```

On initial page load this works and returns data from an api and renders the content. However on changing the route, the `loadSearch` function is fired but the  `dispatch` (which returns the actual data) doesn't.

Comment: Please post code for `loadDestination` and `loadProperties`.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli - added those functions. By adding in a `console.log` into either of those I can see the initial page load, but doesn't fire again on route change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your code to this. You missed a `dispatch`.

**Assumption** : You are using redux-thunk, and the component has access to dispatch via props (connected). Since you mentioned that you are dispatching on page load, I think this is the case.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
   const {dispatch} = this.props;
   if (this.props.params != nextProps.params) {
      nextProps.dispatch(loadSearch(nextProps.params));
   }
}
```